# Is an online store with no SSL secure? The merchant account page has SSL, tho

Tags: security, ssl, paypal, e-commerce

I'm designing an online store with Wix.

They have a great graphic interface which allows non-developers like me to build a professional-looking online store.

However, since I'm a noob in online security, I have this concern - the Wix webpage doesn't support SSL within their pages. But as soons as the customer clicks check out to begin the paying process, he is redirected away from the Wix site to the merchant account page (like paypal etc). The merchant do support SSL.

I'm assuming that although the Wix webpage doesn't support SSL, there is no risk envolved for the customer since he'll be entering his credid card info etc in the merchant account page. Is this correct? If I'm not clear, here is the Wix explanation for the matter:

> **Is Wix eCommerce secure?**
>
> When a customer makes a purchase on a Wix eCommerce site or a site with a PayPal or the Add to Cart button, the only information added by the customer on the Wix site is the product and any product options. Once a customer clicks Checkout, the customer is redirected away from the Wix site and to your merchant account page. Any personal or payment details that the customer has to enter are therefore not entered on the Wix site but rather on the merchant account site which is secured by the merchant account. For more information about exactly how they encrypt and secure payment information, please contact the relevant merchant account.

I'm also assuming only this risk (from the customer's perspective). Are there more risks involved in the Wix website by not supporting SSL? Maybe hacking the website or something? (from the seller's perspective)

Comment: If it helps, certain potential customers (myself included) will absolutely refuse to so much as set up an account on any site that's delivered over HTTP instead of HTTPS, much less get past account setup to a login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might be suitable for serverfault.com instead.
But as it's related to development I'll try to answer it to the best of my ability:

When the connection is not carried over SSL (or any other security measure), the traffic is interceptable and malleable. This means that you can not trust that the data you are getting is actually from the user, unaltered. Additionaly, the user cannot trust that he is in fact talking to your server directly without someone in the middle snooping or altering the data.

Seeing as the payment system is a separate system that does allow for SSL, then you have the most obvious security issue covered. It is then up to you to evaluate whether anything up to that point can be considered sensitive. (for example username and password, if the store requires a login).

A good rule of thumb is that *"Anything not encrypted is potentially known by anyone. In addition it is also alterable."*  Say a user wants to place an order, and clicks the appropriate buttons and links to get to the payment system. Now, if a MITM attacker wants to snoop the credit card details, he can intercept the traffic and substitute the buttons and link to trick the user to his own system, made to look like yours, with the only purpose of gathering credit card details. Attacks like this are possible because the average user doesn't know or care about the danger of accepting certificates from untrusted sources, and it is hard to combat unless awareness is raised around the issue. I have seen online shops  display a warning before accessing the payment system that the user needs to verify that the certificate actually stems from their server, and that the URL is still refers to their webshop.

...But i digress. To sum up: You've got the important part secure. As for the rest, there are some pitfalls, but manageable if handled properly.

Comment: Let me ask you one more thing, please? I am already in touch with Wix's team but I'd like to have more than one take on this.
The domain I own in Hostgator does have SSL. When I link my Wix webpage to my Hostgator domain with SSL, will my website still have the security flaws? I'm guessing it will but I'm not sure. thx a lot